# Trying to add an HTML class attribute to jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

I'm trying to get the class name from an HTML div elements and add it to an existing object. What's maddening is that I can make it work, but every syntax error checker I put it into says the code is wrong. I've searched pretty thoroughly, but I don't even know how to phrase the question, really. Here's the code which DOESN'T throw the error:

```
$.each( $(objDiv).children('div'), function(){
    var field = $(this).attr('class');
    var value = $(this).text();
    var add = { field : value };
    $.extend(obj, add);
});
```

But the problem is that it puts "field" in as a literal string for the field

*object
{label: "level3a", **field**: "Authoritatively enhance client-centric deliverables after sustainable expertise."}*

*object
{label: "level3a", **field:** "Completely embrace clicks-and-mortar data without ubiquitous meta-services."}*

not the class name value. To get around that, I put brackets around "field":

```
$.each( $(objDiv).children('div'), function(){
    var field = $(this).attr('class');
    var value = $(this).text();
    var add = { [field] : value };
    $.extend(obj, add);
}
```

And it gives me the result I'm looking for,

*object
{label: "level3a", **ClassA**: "Authoritatively enhance client-centric deliverables after sustainable expertise."}*

*object
{label: "level3a", **ClassB:** "Completely embrace clicks-and-mortar data without ubiquitous meta-services."}*

but somehow it's incorrect. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here, or a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't tell you why that's wrong (or why it works, for that matter), I can tell you a more "proper" way to do it.

You'd declare `add` as an empty object like so: `add = {};`

Then you can add the field as a property to it like so: `add[field] = value;`

This will give you an object `add` with the model: `{ ClassA: "Your text here" }`

Please refer to the types of property accessors for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors. The method detailed above uses "Bracket Notation"

**Edit:** So apparently in ECMA6 what you wrote is valid javascript, using what's called a *ComputedPropertyName*. However it's not supported by all browsers yet, so until browser support for ECMA6 gets better you're better off using the bracket-notation property name method. See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274327/2748503

Comment: That got me a working solution -- thanks for the answer and the additional info!

Comment: Hey, check out my edit, I found the answer to why your code works.